# How to use Assert.Areequal pass on match of only expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert

For example the below only should get pass

```
 Assert.AreEqual("abc", "abcd");
```

the above example is only for sample. Actually im testing different service responses are equal. Thanks in advance.

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 Assert.AreEqual(serializer.Serialize(A_response.Address), serializer.Serialize(B_response.Address));
```

The issue is B_response.address are have all properties of A_response with some other properties.

Comment: `For example the below only should get pass` Why should it pass? They aren't equal... How are you defining equality?

Comment: measn its enough to  satifiy the expected only not for exactly same. For example abc is the expected value but actual is  abcd than it should pass.

Comment: Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.stringassert.startswith.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 do what you need?

Comment: Its does only for string values . But actual comparison is between two objects.

Comment: There is nothing that does that for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `NUnit.Framework` there are many constraints that could verify two object

eg.

```
        Assert.That("abcd", Does.StartWith("abc"))
```